# How can I do a bootstrap distribution with R programming?

Tags: r

I've been looking for a way to make a bootstrap distribution with R programming. Has R a pre-builded function to do that? what is standard procedure?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done so easily with the R functions `replicate` and `sample` that there is not really a point in a function for that. This draws 2000 bootstrap samples from a heavily non-normal set of observations:

```
observations <-  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 400, 401, 400)
bootstrapped <- replicate(2000, sample(observations, replace = TRUE))
```

You can inspect the first 15 bootstrapped samples

```
> bootstrapped[, 1:15]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]    1  400    2    1    1    2  400  400    1   400     1   400     1     1     1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    1  400    1     1     1     1   400     1     1
 [3,]  401    2    1    1    1  401    1    1    1     1   400     1   400     1   400
 [4,]  400    1    1    1    1    1    1  400    1     1     2     1     1     1     2
 [5,]    1  400  400    2    1    1    2  400    1     1   400   400   400   401   400
 [6,]    1  400    1  400    1  400    2    2    2     1     2     2   400     1   400
 [7,]    2    1    2    1    2    1    1    1    1   400     1     1   401     1     2
 [8,]    2    1    1    2    1    1  400    2    1     1     2     1   400   400     2
 [9,]    1    1    2    1    2  401    1    1    2     1     1   400     1   400     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1  400    1    1  400    1   401   401   401     1     1   400
```

Each column is a random replicate. Next, you probably want to apply some function to your samples. You can do that with `apply` with `margin = 2`. Let's compute a trimmed mean

```
trimmed.means <-apply(bootstrapped, 2, function(x) mean(x, trim = .1))
hist(trimmed.means)
```

All of that being said there are obviously packages on CRAN concerning bootstrapping that can easily be found via google. Which is usefull and when they are usefull will depend on what you plan to do in detail.
Read an introduction to the `boot` package in this article by A. Canty R-News Dec 2002: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2002-3.pdf as an example.

For further questions consider that asking about how something is done in R or in SAS or in Python or in Julia is not on topic on CrossValidated (try StackOverflow for that). However what should be done statistics wise or why something should be done instead of the other usually is on topic on CrossValidated. It seems like a small thing but it will make the difference of a thread being closed or not.

Comment: There's a package `boot` *in the standard R installation* that supports bootstrapping, including some more sophisticated intervals like the studentised t and BCa.

Comment: I know. It is mentioned in my answer and a link to the R-Journal (back then "R-News") is contained in my answer.